# Google Vision OCR

Tags: c#, google-vision

I am trying to read handwritten text from an image using Google Vision API. But the problem is, every time I scan the document (in which I need to recognize handwritten text) and pass it to Google API, the text comes up in a different block. Even though I am scanning the same page. For, eg, the First time the text will come up in Block 8 & next time I scan the document, the text is coming up in Block 10. There is no inconsistency.

I understand the position of text in blocks depends on the scanned document. But is there a better way of going and reading the text?

I know where the handwritten text will be on the scanned doc, but how to determine the position of that text using this google API.